# Evaluating $2\log_{4} (\cos 67^\circ) + \log_{2}(\cos 23^\circ) + \log_{1/2}(\cos 44^\circ)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, logarithms

How to calculate the following?

$$2\log_{4} (\cos 67^\circ) + \log_{2}(\cos 23^\circ) + \log_{1/2}(\cos 44^\circ)$$

Comment: Remember that $\log_a(b)=\frac{\log_c(b)}{\log_c(a)}$, $\log_a(b)+\log_a(c)=\log_a(bc)$ and $c\log_a(b)=\log_a(b^c)$, this should solve this problem

Comment: + some cosine rules

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about a problem (eg, *What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?*). This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to make a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\log_4(\cos67^\circ)=\dfrac{\log\cos67^\circ}{\log4}=\dfrac{\log\cos67^\circ}{2\log2}$$

Use $\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$

finally, $$2\cos67^\circ\cos23^\circ=2\sin(90-67)^\circ\cos23^\circ=2\sin(2\cdot23^\circ)$$